# Formula Moving Data To Second Page If Criteria in Range is Met

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm working on a Google Sheet Project that will move data from one page to another. I need the formula to search a range ( `'Booth Placement'!O2:O1000=133`), if a cell is equal to the set value it will then write the data from the same row `'Booth Placement'!A2:A1000`.

I know the IF can only work for one column and not a range spanning multiple columns. What should I switch the formula below?

`=IF('Booth Placement'!O2:O1000=133,'Booth Placement'!A2:A1000,"")`

I am trying to keep this formula as simple as possible since I will have to change the value it is searching for on each cell on the second page. I've googled this for two days and I'm pretty sure I'm just missing the obvious. Any/All Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=FILTER('Booth Placement'!A2:A1000; 'Booth Placement'!O2:O1000=133)
```

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF('Booth Placement'!O2:O1000=133; 'Booth Placement'!A2:A1000; ))
```

Comment: The first one works like a charm. The ARRAYFORMULA comes back as #REF when you add more than one to a page. I think its because I have multiples of the formula running inside the same coloum, just with different crtiera it is searching for.

Comment: but be carefull with filter, because some blank row or not match data will be ommited

Comment: And with filter, the result will be not in same row

Comment: in this matter I suggest you used the second one, except you don't need your result at destination page in same row.

Comment: @player0 I started have some trouble in actual application. Both of these porovide errors when there would be more than one result in the same coloumn. I've attached a picture of the map it is moving info to based on booth number. https://imgur.com/a/9lcLbF2